# ¿Como modifico una llave primaria a FK? (sin eliminar la tabla)

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero modificar una llave primaria (id_empleado) de una tabla que supuse que deberia haber sido una PK Compuesta. Pero ahora que ya la relacione uno de sus pk a otra tabla quiero cambiar la otra pk, que no esta relacionada a ninguna tabla, a FK. Dropeando la tabla y volviendo a crear no me lo permite, ya que la primera pk ya esta relacionada con la otra tabla.

````
create table if not exists vendedores (
Id_vendedor int not null auto_increment,
Id_empleado int not null,
Nombre varchar (50),
Primary key (Id_vendedor)
);```

intentando dropear la tabla me sale el siguiente error: Error Code: 3730. Cannot drop table 'vendedores' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'pedidos_ibfk_2' on table 'pedidos'.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejecuta estas dos queries simultáneamente:

```
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
DROP TABLE vendedores;
```

De esta forma conseguirás saltarte la protección de la FK. Tanto para eliminar la tabla completa como para modificar la FK.

Answer (score 0):

En este ejemplo que muestro ahora es una BD "empresa" con dos tablas cliente y vendedor.

De esta forma puedes cambiar la PK y posteriormente modificarla a FK, sin eliminar la tabla. Saltarse la protección de la FK es mala practica

Puedes cambiar los datos de mi ejemplo al tuyo

```sql
ALTER TABLE `empresa`.`vendedor` 
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_vendedor`)
;
ALTER TABLE `empresa`.`vendedor` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `id_cliente_fk`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_cliente`)
  REFERENCES `empresa`.`cliente` (`id_cliente`);
```